# Xamarin page model

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to make a simple application with xamarin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Content Page
      xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
      xmlns:redcorner="clr-namespace:RedCorners.Forms;assembly=RedCorners.Forms"
      xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
      ios:Page.UseSafeArea="True"
      x:Class="CargoTracking.view.Login"
      ControlTemplate="{StaticResource LoginTemplate}"
      NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
      <ContentPage.Content>
```

It is very difficult to write these codes and it can be very challenging when I want to make changes. I'm a professional web developer and in my operations I model the header and footer and pass it to the required pages through each router. Is it possible to do this kind of operation in xamarin or is there an alternative solution?

Comment: create your own base page that includes any standard headers or footers

Comment: @Jason Can you give an example of this issue with the project or it can be a sample project file?

Comment: google `xamarin forms make a custom base page`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of doing this in my Knowledge is extending the content page:

```
 public class BasePage : ContentPage
 {
   
    public ICommand CartItemCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand NotificationPageCommand { get; set; }
    public BasePage() : base()
    {
        CartItemCommand = new Command(async () => await GoCartItemCommand());
        NotificationPageCommand = new Command(GoNotificationPage);
    }

}
```

And once you are done with that just use this BasePage everywhere in Place of ContentPage

**In your XAML**

```
<customControls:Basepage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="NameSpace.MainPage"    
        xmlns:customControls="Your base control NameSpace"
        x:Name="Main"
        NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True">


</customControls:Basepage>
```

**And in your Xaml.cs file**

```
public partial class MainPage: BasePage
```

See to it that both partial classes inherit from one base class i.e BasePage or ContentPage as per your need.

Design your headers and footers in your basepage and then use them as you please

Good luck revert in case of queries!